# Load the full node in a popup when clicking on a view row

Tags: ajax, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

I'm currently developing a Drupal 7 website, and I have a view that displays the title and the main image of a certain content type.

I would like to make sure when you click on the view row (the small preview with title and image) that the full node is being displayed in a popup window. This way no new page need to load and I can see the full content of the selected item.

I tried some stuff out with ajax in the views module but i can't get this to work. Any ideas on how I could make this happen? I Looked for a module that is able to this but couldn't find one so far.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to avoid any modification in contrib module , use hook provided if necessary.  you can create own trigger with custom javascript + custom url callback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Node pop-up](https://www.drupal.org/project/npop) module

It creates paths for popup node view without any dependency.

Enable the module and Create link by Setting **data-npop="NODE_NID"**(recomended).

or else you can set **href** attribute as
    "**ajax/npop/node/[nid]/load/nojs**", where [nid] nid of node and set
    attribute **class** as "**use-ajax**".

Answer (score 0):

- Install https://www.drupal.org/project/modal
- Enable view node submodule
- Create url in your view `<a href="/modal/node/NID/nojs" class="ctools-use-modal">View</a>.`
- It's all :)